# Find out global jndi name from within bean

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, jndi

I have multiple JavaEE6 applications (.war) deployed in a JBoss 7.4.
All of these applications contain a common library which provides a Singleton-Bean implementation. 
This singleton-bean is configured differently for each application using the JBoss modules folder and should log some application specific information - This is working already fine.

However I have difficulties distinguishing which log line comes from which application.

When the server starts for each application (my-app1, my-app2, ...) I have the following output in the log:

```
INFO  10:45:54,998 (EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:setupJNDIBindings:183) -JNDI bindings for session bean named MyBean in deployment unit deployment "my-app1.war" are as follows:
java:global/my-app1/MyBean!my.package.MyBean
java:app/my-app1/MyBean!my.package.MyBean
java:module/MyBean!my.package.MyBean
java:global/my-app1/MyBean
java:app/my-app1/MyBean
java:module/MyBean
```

This output is exactly what I need, so I would like to retrieve the global jndi name under which MyBean was deployed in my code:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class MyBean {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyBean.class);

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        String appName = ""; // .getGlobalJndiNameOfThisInstance();
        log.info("MyBean available for application " + appName);
        // and log further application specific info
    }

}
```

When researching this I only find vast information on how to lookup beans via jndi, which I don't need. Can I extract the app-name somehow via creating a `new InitialContext()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to lookup the name. It is available via jndi-lookup under the name `java:app/AppName` or `java:module/ModuleName`.

I extended my EJB as follows:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class MyBean {

    @Resource(lookup = "java:app/AppName")
    String appName;

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyBean.class);

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        log.info("MyBean available for application " + appName);
        // and log further application specific info
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.naming.*;
import net.sf.extcos.ComponentQuery;
import net.sf.extcos.ComponentScanner;

public class ServiceLocator {

public <T extends Object> T lookup(Class<T> interfaceLocal) {
    try {
        return (T) getInitialContext().lookup(buildJNDIWildfly(interfaceLocal));
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public <T> String buildJNDIWildfly(final Class<T> interfaceLocal) {
    Class<? extends T> clazz = getImplementorOf(interfaceLocal, getPackagesToScan());
    if (clazz != null) {
        URL url = getUrlOfClass(clazz);
        String module = getModuleName(url);
        return "global/" + module + "/" + clazz.getSimpleName() + "!" + interfaceLocal.getName();
    }
    return null;
}

public String[] getPackagesToScan() {
    // important to reduce range of search
    return new String[] { "my.package.of.ejbs" };
}

public static URL getUrlOfClass(Class<?> clazz) {
    if (clazz == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    String resourceName = clazz.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class";
    ClassLoader classLoader = clazz.getClassLoader();
    if (classLoader == null) {
        classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    }
    return classLoader.getResource(resourceName);
}

public <T> Class<? extends T> getImplementorOf(final Class<T> interfaceLocal, final String... packagesToScan) {
    // https://sourceforge.net/projects/extcos
    final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    ComponentScanner scanner = new ComponentScanner();
    scanner.getClasses(new ComponentQuery() {
        @Override
        protected void query() {
            select().from(packagesToScan).andStore(
                    thoseBeing(and(annotatedWith(Stateless.class), implementorOf(interfaceLocal))).into(classes))
                    .returning(none());
        }
    });
    if (classes.size() > 0) {
        return (Class<? extends T>) classes.iterator().next();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

private String getModuleName(URL urlOfClass) {
    if (urlOfClass != null) {
        // Ex:
        // vfs:/opt/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/deployments/myEar.ear/my-module.jar/my/interface/local/MyInterface.class
        String filePath = urlOfClass.getFile();
        int earPosition = filePath.lastIndexOf(".ear");
        int jarPosition = filePath.lastIndexOf(".jar");
        String earName = null;
        String moduleName = null;
        if (earPosition >= 0) {
            earName = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('/', earPosition) + 1, earPosition);
        }
        if (jarPosition >= 0) {
            moduleName = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('/', jarPosition) + 1, jarPosition);
            if (earName != null) {
                moduleName = earName + "/" + moduleName;
            }
        }
        return moduleName;
    }

    return null;
}

private InitialContext getInitialContext() {
    try {

        Hashtable<String, String> props = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        props.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        return new InitialContext(props);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: this is my solution.

Comment: add dependency:  `code <dependency>
   <groupId>net.sf.extcos</groupId>
   <artifactId>extcos</artifactId>
   <version>0.4b</version>
  </dependency> `